# \toprule over two minipages?

Tags: tables, booktabs

I have two tables side by side, in one minipage each. My question is, how to use `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` to span the entire width of the `table` environment (as opposed to spanning only the current `tabular`)? By "entire width" I don't mean literally having length equal to `\textwidth`, but to be smart about it like `\toprule` is.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  % I want a \toprule (?) here (?) to (cleverly) span
  % the entire table environment.
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      \toprule            % This spans only this (leftmost) table.
      \\
      % Table Content.
      \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
  ~
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      \toprule            % This spans only this (rightmost) table.
      \\
      % Table Content.
      \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I remember tables can be nested, so instead of your minipages you could use a table with one row two cells, each of which is a table. Untested

Comment: I might try that, will let you know how it works.

Comment: Be aware that @daleif terminology could be misleading: you cannot nest `table` environments (which produce a floating object and can therefore be used in “outer paragraph mode” only); what you can nest are `tabular` environments.

Comment: @GuM you are totally right, I meant tabular not table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest tables.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  p{\dimexpr.5\textwidth}
  @{}
  p{\dimexpr.5\textwidth}
  @{}
}
\toprule
\begin{tabular}{c}
\toprule
Table Content. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{c}
\toprule
Table Content. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be good to add some inline comments about what does the @{} part do.

Comment: @dow It removes the intercolumn space